# Can a td be inside a td

Tags: html, html-table, w3c, w3c-validation

It may be a nonsense question, and I know we have to follow standards as much as possible. But can `<td>` be a direct child of another `<td>`, like this:

```
<td class="parent">
    <td class="child">
        <!-- Some info -->
    </td>
</td>
```

Or it's obligatory to create another `<table>` with a new `<tr>` before adding the `<td>`, which can become heavily populated with table tags and become clustered...

Comment: Putting an entire table in the cell isn't cluttered --- it's comprehensible.  Don't write nonsense HTML to save typing.

Comment: My recommendation: Stay away from nested tables!

Comment: They have their place --- some things are semantically best expressed as nested tables.

Comment: @JasonFruit - Like what? When was the last time you saw a nested table printed in a normal book (i.e. one not related in any way to HTML)?

Comment: @Alohci --- Conveniently enough, just two days ago, in a book giving specifications of early aircraft.  Each row had an area for additional information, which was in a few cases tabular.

Comment: Good thing the rest of us aren't browsing specs of early aircraft, the internet would be a more terrible place.

Comment: On the other hand,  this is clearly not a good use for it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

not directly but you could place table inside td

```
<td class="parent">
   <table><tr>
    <td class="child">
        <!-- Some info -->
    </td>
   </tr></table>
</td>
```

Comment: You could also put a div inside a <td> and it would be slightly less heinous.

Answer (score 4):

No, `<td>` may not be a child of a `<td>`. A `<td>` may only be a child of a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2):

it's better to create a new table tag.

The example you give is not standard and the behavior can be different from a browser to another one

Answer (score 0):

The problem with not following standards like putting a `<td>` tag inside a `<dt>`, is that you cannot guarantee that the result is the same for all browsers, or that the next update of any browser will for example not simply ignore wrongly-used tags.

As a sidenote: we, as a developer comunity, have cried and shouted for Internet Explorer to finally start to take the standards seriously, so now let's not start making a mess ourselves!