# Finding if title exists in tag BS4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find if an specific title exists within a tag and if it doesn't contain it print the text within the t variable. 
So far I can pull the entire 'td' of the tag with:

```
for t in soup.findAll("td",{"class" : "someClass"}):
```

but when I use:

```
title = "someTitle"
if title in t:
   print "contains title"
else:
   print "doesn't contain title
```

It doesn't seem to look for the existence of the title and pass through everything anyway.What am I doing wrong?

Example HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <td class="someClass">
  <td>
   Text
  </td>
  <img title ="someTitle">
  </td>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you HTML when put into beautifulsoup : `<html>
     <body>
      <td class="someClass">
      </td>
      <td>
       Text
      </td>
      <img title="someTitle"/>
     </body>
    </html>` where `<img>` is not even inside the `<td class="someClass"></td>`

Comment: you can't have a `<td>` cell within another cell just caused problems with beautifulsoup.

Comment: In the actual html it has everything contained within a single td. Is there no way to circumvent this with bs4?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484826/can-a-td-be-inside-a-td) stated that it is not allowed for `<td>` to be the parent of another `<td>`. I don't think it is a bs4 problem, it is the html's problem. I don't think there is a workaround on this.

Comment: So the logic isnt wrong its just that bs4 can't find the td of a td?Guess ill just need to find another way,cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Though `<td>` cannot have nested `<td>`, we can somehow extract the image title here.

**Python 2 Code:**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''
<html>
 <body>
  <td class="someClass">
  <td>
   Text
  </td>
  <img title ="someTitle">
  </td>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(html)
tds = soup.findAll("td",{"class":"someClass"})
for td in tds:
    td_pretty = td.prettify()
    td_split_list = [line.strip() for line in td_pretty.split("\n")]
    img = bs(td_split_list[4])
    print img.find("img").get("title")
```

**Output:**

```
someTitle
```

We have used the prettify method ([see documentation here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing)) of BeautifulSoup